# Java java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 error message

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors, syntax-error

So my code is working except when I was testing the method `showSortedRows()`. It showed me my desired output but at the same time gave me this error message. I don't really know why, please help me!

> Error message: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>   at
>   Driver0.showSortedRows(Driver0.java:90)
>   at
>   Driver0.choice(Driver0.java:35)   at Driver0.main(Driver0.java:21)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Driver0
{
   public static int [][] array;
   public static int dimension1, dimension2;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Welcome to Project 0.");
      System.out.println("What is the name of the data file? ");
      System.out.print("> ");
      String file = input.nextLine();
      readFile(file);
      String nextCommand = "";
      while (!(nextCommand.equals("quit"))) 
      {
         System.out.println("\nNext command");
         System.out.print("> ");
         nextCommand = input.nextLine();
         choice (nextCommand);
      }

   }

   public static void choice(String command) 
   {
      switch (command) 
      {
         case "help": System.out.println("show array\nwhich rows sorted\nwhich cols sorted"+
                                     "increase row i by n\nincrease col j by n\nquit\n");
                  break;
     case "show array": showArray();
                        break;
     case "which rows sorted": showSortedRows();
                               break;
     /*case "which cols sorted": showSortedCols();
     case "increase row i by n": increaseRow();
     case "increase col j by n": increaseCol();*/

      }
   }


    public static void readFile(String file)
    {
       try
       {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(file));
            dimension1 = sc.nextInt();
            dimension2 = sc.nextInt();
            array = new int[dimension1][dimension2];
            while (sc.hasNext()) 
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < dimension1; row++)
                {
                for (int column = 0; column < dimension2; column++) 
                {
                     array[row][column] = sc.nextInt();
                }
             }

            }
             sc.close();
          }

         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.out.println("Error: file not found or insufficient       requirements.");
          }
          }
         public static void showArray() 
         {
              for (int rows = 0; rows < dimension1; rows++) 
              {
                    for (int col = 0; col < dimension2; col++) 
                    {
                         System.out.printf("%2d ", array[rows][col]);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                 }
              }

             public static void showSortedRows()
             {
                  for (int rw = 0; rw < dimension1; rw++)
                  {
                      for (int cl = 0; cl < dimension2; cl++)
                      {
                         if (array[rw][cl] <= array[rw][cl+1])
                         System.out.printf("%2d,", rw);
                         rw++;
                      }
                      System.out.println();
                    }     

                 }

              }
```

Comment: Do you know how to read exception stack trace and debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop runs until `cl < dimension2` so `array[rw][cl+1]` will cause the error.

You have to change your loop to `for (int cl = 0; cl < dimension2-1; cl++)`

Comment: i fixed it like what you said but it still gave me the same error, so i do not know what is happening

Comment: @SylviaWang are you sure that you have cleaned and rebuild your Project?

Comment: @Jens if dimension2 is > dimension1, the rw++ will cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException as well.

Comment: @Gosu Oh have overseen it.

Comment: @SylviaWang Do not change the variable of the Loop inside of it. That is very bad practice.

Comment: @Jens then can you please tell me what can i do with it? please i am only starting to learn Java data structure so i really do not know how to fix it.

Comment: i can post up how the sample run should look like if that helps you guys get idea

Comment: @SylviaWang Think about your algorithm. Looks like that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is this line:

```
if (array[rw][cl] <= array[rw][cl+1])
```

When cl is `dimension2-1`, cl + 1 causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

By the way, are you sure the `rw++` within the double for loop is correct?
Is it supposed to be part of the `if` condition?
When dimension2 is > dimension1, it can also cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**`showSortedRows()` should be:**

```
public static void showSortedRows() {
    for (int rw = 0; rw < dimension1; rw++) {
        boolean sortedRow = true;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int cl = 0; cl < (dimension2 - 1); cl++) {
            sb.append(array[rw][cl]).append(" ");
            if (array[rw][cl] > array[rw][cl + 1]) {
                sortedRow = false;
            }
            if((cl + 1) == (dimension2 - 1)) {
                sb.append(array[rw][cl + 1]).append(" ");
            }
        }
        if(sortedRow) {
            System.out.println("Row " + (rw + 1) + " is sorted!");
            System.out.println("Row contents: " + sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Row 1 is sorted!
Row contents: 2 3 4 5 10 
Row 3 is sorted!
Row contents: -3 -1 0 1 5
```

Comment: i fixed it like what you posted but it still gave me the same error

Comment: @SylviaWang Well you need to tell us what is the error? Include the contents of the input file in your question.

Comment: i used rw++; is because i want to print out all the row numbers that are sorted, so I think this is right but i am not sure if it supposed to be in if.

Comment: the content of the input file is like this:
3 5        
2 3 4 5 10
4 5 2 3 7
-3 -1 0 1 5

Comment: @SylviaWang remove the `rw++` and see how it goes? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: first line of input file: 3 5

Comment: i tried but if i remove the rw++ then it will not print out all the row numbers of the sorted rows

Comment: @SylviaWang Code is working now, you shouldn't be throwing your code for us to debug for you. Look at my updated `showSortedRows`.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of this line:

```
 if (array[rw][cl] <= array[rw][cl+1])
```

Whats happening is that, when your variable `cl` becomes equal to `dimension2 - 1` in the last iteration of the inner loop, it checks for the `[cl][dimension2]`th index. Which is not present in the array. Your array is of the size `[row][dimension2]` which means it counts from `0` to `row - 1` for rows and `0` to `dimension2 - 1` for columns. And still it is trying to access `dimension2`th index. And hence it gives you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

## SOLUTION:

Your loop must be:

```
for(int cl = 0; cl < dimension2 - 1; cl ++)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i tried to change it like what you said but i got the exactly same error message as what's on top and nothing changed, so it is so weird.

Comment: Hey coz you are trying to increment `rw` in the loop body. Are you sure you want that `rw++` after the if statement in the inner loop?